# Azure Devops: Scheduled Service Requests

Tags: azure-devops

We have certain service requests that have to be completed on repeatedly each week/month/quarter. Is there any easy ways to schedule this so we don't have to manually recreate them each month?

Comment: What kind of service request? How did you config the service request?

Answer (score 0):

If you can create the service request from REST api, you can associate the request with a build pipeline, by adding a task to run the request and [setting YAML scheduled triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml). For example:

```
schedules:
- cron: "0 0 * * *"
  displayName: Daily midnight build
  branches:
    include:
    - master
    - releases/*
    exclude:
    - releases/ancient/*
- cron: "0 12 * * 0"
  displayName: Weekly Sunday build
  branches:
    include:
    - releases/*
  always: true
```

Scheduled triggers cause a pipeline to run on a schedule defined using [cron syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#supported-cron-syntax).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve, but you can create a scheduled build. Inside this build as one of step you may create this service request.

This is how you define scheduled build using cron:

```
schedules:
- cron: "0 0 * * *"
  displayName: Daily midnight build
  branches:
    include:
    - master
```

More details you can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

But if you explain how this is related to Azure DevOps I may propose better answer if it possible.